# Accessing values from dynamodb based on a column value - python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamo db having table with column names url, data, date and entity

```
    url                       data                    date                    entity
 https://www.google.com     search engine             21-09-2021                Website
```

I am trying to access the values in data column by using values in url column as search tag. How it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please let me know are you using this way?

```
    import boto3
    from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
    response = table.query(
      KeyConditionExpression=Key('url').eq('https://www.google.com')
    )
    print(response['data'])
```